# Where is the Parsamani(Gold Stone) which Satyabhama's father had?

Tags: krishna, satyabhama

I read a book on Krishna written by K.M. Munshi called "KRISHNAVATAR" in which author wrote that, Satyabhama's father had a parasmani(Gold Stone), and with proper pooja of that stone turn anything into gold.

I am sure that, the Mani was not destroyed. So does anybody know where is that Mani now?  I also heard from lore that, that Mani way curse object. Is it true?

Comment: Why are you so sure that **The Mani is not destroyed** ?

Comment: I read on Mani further, so two thing i found, one is that, there is no mention for Mani is destroyed by someone, second, from one article i also read that, Mani is curse object.

Comment: So was it a **Gold Stone**, or a stone that can turn anything into **Gold** ? And who is "lore" ?

Comment: The name of this stone is 'Syamantaka' gem. Some belief is that it is none other than the Kohinoor gem which is in England in Queen's crown. But there is no proof or that.

Comment: Kohinoor doesnt turn anything into gold.

Comment: @Aby: if you find any info link regarding it, it would be great!

Comment: @sysinit : there is a process of POOJA with Syamantaka, and after that Syamantaka can turn anything into Gold. that POOJA related brief information is written in that book, which i mention.

Comment: The name of the gem is Shamantaka mani not  parasmani.

Comment: Mani which Satyabhama's father had was [Syamantaka Mani](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/10/56)?